# How to fill in empty spaces in a 2d array with specific set of characters

Tags: arrays, c

I must fill in the empty indexes in my 2d array with adjacent letters ending at "z". For example, if there are 3 open spaces at the end of my array --(empty indexes)--then those 3 indexes will be filled with "x, y,z". I have two inquiries I need assistance with.

1. How can I check if an index in my 2d array is empty?  (given that a string of characters will be supplied to the array, which may leave open empty indexes).
2. How do I go about filling in the indexes with the adjacent letters ending to z, For example, I would know how to fill index 1 with "z", index 2 with "y, index 3 with "x", but how do I manipulate the program to predetermine where from the alphabet I have to start from to fill the array ending at letter z & then proceeding to fill up the rest of the array? As the indexes must be filled in left to right with the most right index ending at z.

```
float keylength = strlen(encryptionKey);
float textLength = strlen(completedtext);
int rowValue = ceil(textLength / keylength);
// outputs row value taking encryption key length & text length 

char myArray[rowValue][strlen(encryptionKey)];
int counter; 

// code to have characters added to 2d array .
while (strlen(completedtext) > counter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowValue; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(encryptionKey); j++)
        {
            counter++;
            if (myArray[i][j] == NULL)
            {
                myArray[i][j] = "z"; 
            }
            myArray[i][j] = completedtext[counter-1];
            printf("%c ", myArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried creating a helper function but it is not supplying the desired results after testing

```
int countWhiteSpaces(char c[4][5])
{
    int totalCount; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (c[i][j] == " ")
            totalCount++; 
        }
    }

    printf("Your results are below ! \n");
    return totalCount;
}
```

Comment: What does your beginners material say about `" "` and `' '` and their difference?

Comment: There's no such thing as a value in your array being "empty". You must define what value to use for that meaning. A reasonable choice would be the value `0`, and for cases like this you should initialize every value of the array to that before reading other data into it.

Comment: Also note that C doesn't have the concept of null values. All elements of you arrays will have a value, but if it's not initialized then that value will be indeterminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit too much going wrong with this program to fix it without a bit of reworking. As written, it's a bit pointless to try and represent "empty" values in your array.

The way your loop currently works is that it wants to initialize every array element once. All you need to do is count how many characters of your string have been copied, and then start filling your padding characters from there. You know in advance how many characters that will be.

An easy way to do that is to calculate that in advance and then count that backwards as you fill characters.

Example:

```
int keyLength = strlen(encryptionKey);
int textLength = strlen(completedText);
int rowCount = (textLength + keyLength - 1) / keyLength; // round up
char myArray[rowCount][keyLength];

int textPos = 0;
int padding = rowCount * keyLength - textLength;
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < keyLength; j++)
    {
        if (textPos < textLength) {
            myArray[i][j] = completedText[textPos];
            textPos++;
        } else {
            padding--;
            myArray[i][j] = 'z' - padding;
        }
        printf("%c ", myArray[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

See that here, `textPos` (a more descriptive name than "counter") walks through your string until it has visited every character. At that point, we start using the `padding` value as an offset from the character `'z'`. It was already calculated to be just the right size so that'll end up at zero when you visit the last position.

Example output with the key `"foobar"` and the text `"Hello, World!"`:

```
H e l l o , 
  W o r l d 
! v w x y z
```

---

A simpler way to do it exploits the fact that all elements of the array are packed consecutively in memory. You can access it as it it is a 1D array, even though it's 2D. So you can actually copy the string into there in one line, and then do your padding.

```
// Fill array
memcpy(myArray, completedText, textLength);
for(int i = rowCount * keyLength - 1, ch = 'z'; i >= textLength; i--, ch--)
{
    (&myArray[0][0])[i] = ch;
}

// Output
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < keyLength; j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", myArray[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```